# Simultaneous sequencing

Tags: sequence

I was completing two separate sequences, one vertical and one diagonal. I reached the point where one card enabled me to place a marker at the convergence of the two sequences, i.e.: one move gave me the two required sequences to win the game. Does this fall within the rules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have constructed your scenario in the following image. You hold the card for the 2❤️, represented by a darker blue chip.

[image: example sequence]

If the green player has been unable to block this board state from being formed, you may place a chip on the 2❤️ and complete two sequences sharing only one space to win.

This involves a [couple of rules](https://www.jaxgames.com/sequence-game-rules/):

> - You may use any one of the spaces from your first SEQUENCE as part of your second.
> - You cannot remove a marker chip that is already part of a completed SEQUENCE.

There is no rule specifying a single placement may not simultaneously be counted as both your first and second placement.

Comment: Thank you James - good of you to reconstruct the play. I appreciate you having taken the time to do so.

Comment: @PaddyThomas If you accept this answer, please do check the green check mark by it to indicate so.  It helps keep the site a little cleaner (as well as grants some extra rep to poster and answered).